# CGRect vs constraints in programmatic GUI Design?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, frames, cgrect

We use `CGRect` inside a frame specifying the width, height and the exact coordination of the rectangle (shape).

Do I need to specify constrains for the UI elements one by one as well? If yes, why do I need to? How about device rotation (portrait vs. landscape mode)? Do I need to define different positioning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are defining constraints you do not have to specify a CGRect frame for your design. In fact best way is to use NSLayoutConstraints. The reason is if you set the CGRect frame, when your device is rotating most of the time your CGRect can be wrong. At least hight and with. But if you use constraints when your device is rotating it will layout the subviews again automatically. Which means the views will rearrange according to the constraints.

When you set the CGRect frame what it does is, it changes the view's position and dimensions regardless of the constraints. Then if you try to call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` or change the orientation the views will be rearranged according to the constraints regardless the frame you set before.

Comment: pretty neat answer but it would be awesome if it could have come with some coding samples ;)  @LIH

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

Constraints are a rich and descriptive way of describing the size of views. The manually setting of a frame (and autoresizing mask) is a far older pattern and is not as flexible or as powerful. You certainly *can* set the `frame` and `autoresizingMask`, but we generally do not, and we tend to use constraints nowadays.

---

When defining the frame of a view, you have two alternatives:

- Use constraints:

  - Turn off [`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco) and
  - Activate your constraints.
- Using [`autoresizingMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622559-autoresizingmask) and `frame`:

  - Leave `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on;
  - Set the `frame` of the view; and
  - Set the view’s `autoresizingMask`.

---

For example, if you wanted to define an image view to be inset by 50pt horizontally, and 100pt vertically, you could do:

- Use constraints:

  ```
   imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 50),
       imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: -50),
       imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
       imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100)
   ])
  ```
- Use frame/autoresizing mask:

  ```
   imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
   imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
   imageView.frame = view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 50, dy: 100)
  ```

There are a few things to note:

- It is not correct to conclude that setting `frame` manually means that you cannot respond to rotations (or other events that might change the size of the superview). Most, basic resizing logic can be handled quite gracefully with `autoresizingMask`. (Frankly, that is what we did before the auto-layout engine was introduced.)
- Technically, both of these approaches are actually using constraints behind the scenes. The `autoresizingMask`/`frame` with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is just translating the `frame` and `autoresizingMask` into constraints for you.
- The auto-layout engine and constraints are a far richer paradigm:

  - You can easily define constraints between views in different levels of the view hierarchy and/or between layout guides.
  - They support more complicated rules with separate multiplier and constant parameters, inequality operators, cascading priorities, etc.
  - They support dynamic layout for right-to-left languages.
  - They support different layouts for different size traits (e.g. rearranging items dynamically based upon the relative width or height of the view).

  All of these features largely eliminate the need to write code responding to the layout of subviews.

In short, using constraints has largely displaced the older technique of setting the `frame` and `autoresizingMask`.